# Issue Converting a String to a Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a website which is in two languages (English & Russian).

I have a form in which the date is posted as a `string` and I am converting the `string` to a nullable `DateTime` as seen in the snippet of code below.

```
string dts = form["startdatetime"].ToString();
string ets = form["enddatetime"].ToString();

String.Format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", dts);
String.Format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", ets);

DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dts) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dts, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
DateTime? et = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ets) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(ets, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

But, the problem I am getting is when I change my computer's `DateTime` format. It gives me the error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I am testing with the below formats

```
d-M-y displays as 7-‎8-‎11

dd-MM-yy displays as ‎07-‎08-‎11

dd/MM/yy displays as ‎07/08/11

ddd-MMM-yyy displays as Sun-‎Aug-‎2011

ddd, MMM. yyy displays as Sun, ‎Aug. 2011

dddd-MMMM-yyyy displays as ‎Sunday-‎August-‎2011

dddd dd, MMMM yyyy displays as Sunday ‎07, ‎August ‎2011
```

I want to convert my `string` to a nullable `DateTime` if the Windows machine is running on any of the above formats. How should I handle this error?

Comment: You could use Try.Parse before hand to check instead of Parse. But that is quite unexpected, in what format do you change the DateTime that it is not recognized?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information, see [ask] and create a [mcve]. Anyway I guess it's caused because `/` uses the system separator, not the literal `/`. Use `\\/` to denote the literal slash.

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. What are the values of `dts` and `ets` exactly? You try to change your computer datetime format to what? Which datetime you have changed on "region and language"? Your `String.Format` usage does not _effect_ anything on `dts` and `ets` by the way. Have you tried to use `ParseExact` to supply specific format instead? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your problem.

Comment: If you're storing data in `DateTime` variables, at that point it ceases to *have* a format.

Comment: @soner Gonul i have tried paresExact it brigs me same error.

Comment: try DateTime.TryParseExact. It allows an array of formats.

Comment: In the first couple of lines you are calling ToString () without culture.  If the item in your array is a date time will will create a date string using the current default (ui) culture.  Later you try to parse it as a particular culture (which may or may not be the format of the incoming string.  I think you would either have to control the format of the incoming date string or use a sequence of datetime parse statements until one works.  The later option is risky because 1/2/2010 can be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: @DennisSellinger i have handle culture i have try to convert datetime by this code  `DateTime? et = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ets) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(ets, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` i got date in format of 31.12.2015 12:00:00 so how to solve this problem.